# If $ t_n\rightarrow \infty$ and $ g(t_n)\rightarrow p$ we can find another sequence such that the derivative goes to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function such that there exists a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with:
$$
t_n\rightarrow \infty,
$$
$$
g(t_n)\rightarrow p\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

I would like to show that there exists a sequence $\{s_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with:
$$
s_n\rightarrow \infty,
$$
$$
g(s_n)\rightarrow p,
$$
$$
g'(s_n)\rightarrow 0.
$$
I don't know if the result is true, but I guess that the mean value theorem could play a very important role. Nevertheless, I have not been able to prove this, neither to find a counterexample.

Comment: I’m almost certain this is not true. Here is a potential counterexample (though I haven’t thought through a full proof that this is indeed a counterexample, so take it with a grain of salt): let $g(x) = \sin(x)$. Along $t_n =n\pi$ we have $g(t_n) \to 0$. However, anywhere that $g(s) = 0$ we have $g’(s) = \pm 1$ so I don’t believe you can find a sequence $s_n$ which satisfies both $g(s_n) \to 0$ and $g’(s_n) \to 0$. Perhaps you wish for the assumption to be stronger: $g(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Addressing my above comment: this is indeed a counterexample. If $\sin(s_n)\to 0$, then $\lvert \cos(s_n)\rvert \to 1$ since $\sin(s_n)^2 +\cos(s_n)^2 =1$ and so we cannot have $\cos(s_n) \to 0$.

Comment: This probably is true if you don't require $g(s_n)\to p$ (mean value theorem)

Comment: The conjecture is true if $p=\inf g$: this is the celebrated Ekeland variational principle.

Comment: @user160738 I’m not quite seeing how to prove it even if we don’t require that $g(s_n) \to p$. The mean value theorem would give existence of a sequence $s_n$ such that (for example) $\lim g’(s_n)(t_n -t_{n-1}) =\lim (g(t_n) -g(t_{n-1})) = 0$ but this does not ensure that $g’(s_n) \to 0$ since we can’t necessarily bound $(t_n -t_{n-1})$ away from zero.